# How can I post mat-form to API in angular

Tags: angular, angular-http

I have form, and I want post form values to API, but the values can not be posted, how can resolve this error?

- **my html form**:

```
<form #adduser ="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onAddUser(adduser.value)">
  <mat-form-field class="form-fild-width">
     <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
     <input matInput name="first_name" ngModel required>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="form-fild-width">
     <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
     <input matInput name="last_name" ngModel required>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="form-fild-width">
     <mat-label>User Name</mat-label>
     <input matInput name="user_name" ngModel required>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="form-fild-width">
     <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
     <input matInput name="password" ngModel required>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-action-row>
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Add User</button>
  </mat-action-row>
</form>
```

- **my typescript code**:

```
onAddUser(data:{first_name: string, last_name: string, user_name: string, password: string}){
    console.log(data)
    this.http.post('https://my.users.com/users/add?', data,{headers:headers})
    .subscribe((result) => {
      console.warn(result);
    })
  }
```

Comment: 1. Have you tried `console.log(data)` and what is the value of `data`? 2. Have you checked the DevTools --> Network tab for the respective request is sent with the request body correctly? 3. What is your API, how is it expect the data to be received, request body, request parameter, form data?

Comment: @YongShun  ... 1. `colsole.log(data)`  view values that come from my form . 2. in devtools -> network tab --> pyload view values that come from my form. 3. I can podt the value using post man but in code no.

Comment: Please share your implementation for API. How you send the request with the data to API via Postman, with request body, form data or query string param?

Comment: @YongShun, query string param or by pass values via google Chrome search bar

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned that you pass the form value as the query string param, your current implementation in Angular is incorrect as you post the form value in the request body.

You should build the URL with the query string param.

```
onAddUser(data:{first_name: string, last_name: string, user_name: string, password: string}) {
  console.log(data)

  let queryStringPrams = "";
  let i = 0;

  for (let prop in data) {
    if (i > 0)
      queryStringParams  += `&${prop}=${encodeURIComponent(data[prop].toString())}`;
    else 
      queryStringParams  += `${prop}=${encodeURIComponent(data[prop].toString())}`;

    i++;
  }
    
  this.http.post('https://my.users.com/users/add?' + queryStringParams, null, { headers:headers })
    .subscribe((result) => {
      console.warn(result);
    });
}
```

Another approach is applying the [`HttpParams`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) to pass the form value as the query string.

```
onAddUser(data:{first_name: string, last_name: string, user_name: string, password: string}) {
  console.log(data)

  let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();

  for (let prop in data) {
    params = params.append(prop, data[prop]);
  }
    
  this.http.post('https://my.users.com/users/add', null, { headers:headers, params: params })
    .subscribe((result) => {
      console.warn(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: I get error in `obj[prop].toString()` obj un defin. How can resolve this error ?

Comment: Apologize, use `data[prop]` instead of `obj[prop]`.

Comment: also I get error in this line `data[prop]` Could you update your Solution code .

Comment: Can you share the code? What error you get? I can't know what is the error without info provided.